# why should i use getUniform first when modifing uniform values

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm reading the book WebGL Beginner's Guide, when it comes to the code which is write for changing light direction via a keydown event:

```
function processKey(ev){
    var lightDirection = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightDirection);
    var incrAzimuth =   10;
    var incrElevation = 10;

    switch(ev.keyCode){
        case 37: // left arrow
            azimuth -= incrAzimuth;
            break;
        case 38: //up arrow
            elevation += incrElevation;
            break;

        case 39: // right arrow
            azimuth += incrAzimuth;
            break;
        case 40: //down arrow
            elevation -= incrElevation;
            break;
    }

    azimuth %= 360;
    elevation %=360;

    var theta = elevation * Math.PI / 180;
    var phi   = azimuth * Math.PI / 180;

    //Spherical to Cartesian coordinate transformation
    lightDirection[0] = Math.cos(theta)* Math.sin(phi);
    lightDirection[1] = Math.sin(theta);
    lightDirection[2] = Math.cos(theta)* -Math.cos(phi);

    gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightDirection, lightDirection);
}
```

It seems that `var lightDirection = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightDirection);` dosen't make any sense , because

```
lightDirection[0] = Math.cos(theta)* Math.sin(phi);
lightDirection[1] = Math.sin(theta);
lightDirection[2] = Math.cos(theta)* -Math.cos(phi);`
```

do not process any calculation by "lightDirection" , and then it just process the value to the shader.

So I change the line `var lightDirection = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightDirection);` to `var lightDirection;` but the program can't not work as expected.

Comment: Initialize `lightDirection` to an array?

Comment: @gre_gor yes. the return value of getUniform you can see [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getUniform). And I worked fine when I use `var lightDirection = [];` in this case. but obviously, this array is not the same as the returned array.

Comment: Then initialize it as `var lightDirection = new Float32Array(3);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. You should either cache the value in a variable or recompute it every time. For your particular code the second options works perfectly:

```
function processKey(e) {
    // ...
    var lightDirection = [
        Math.cos(theta)* Math.sin(phi),
        Math.sin(theta),
        Math.cos(theta)* -Math.cos(phi)
    ];
    gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightDirection, lightDirection);
}
```

Or even use 'uniform3f' and don't create an array at all:

```
function processKey(e) {
    // ...
    gl.uniform3f(
        prg.uLightDirection,
        Math.cos(theta)* Math.sin(phi),
        Math.sin(theta),
        Math.cos(theta)* -Math.cos(phi)
    );
}
```

Comment: thx ^.^ , `var lightDirection = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightDirection);` initializing the value to a correct data type.

Comment: @aMoving60Kg It's quite a costly way to do that:) Generally speaking, you should avoid function call that read WebGL state or do them early on and cache the results. Call `getUniform` in every event handler just to initialise a variable (and with values you don't even need) is excessive.

Comment: @aMoving60Kg please mark this answer as accepted to let others know the question got adequately answered.